# Output ssh2 stream per line

Tags: php, ssh, libssh2

I am very new in ssh2 with PHP, and need some help.

I am trying to echo php ssh2 output stream line by line

```
if($ssh = ssh2_connect('127.0.0.1', 22)) {
    if(ssh2_auth_password($ssh, 'root', 'password')) {
        $stream = ssh2_exec($ssh, 'ifconfig');
        stream_set_blocking($stream, true);
        $data = '';
        while($buffer = fread($stream, 4096)) {
            $data .= $buffer;
        }
        fclose($stream);
        echo $data; // user
    }
}
```

But the output is not showing line by line. What do I have to do to get the output line by line just like ssh?

Answer (score 0):

Use [`fgets()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.fgets.php). It will read line buffered:

```
while($line = fgets($stream)) {
    echo $line;
}
```

Comment: Hello its giving same result. not line by line output

Comment: @Santu Roy - hek2mgl's answer should work. It returns whenever a new line is encountered.  That said, if you're outputting in a webbrowser you'll need to put `<pre>` tags around it. You could do PHP's nl2br too, I suppose, but I think `<pre>` tags would be better.